# eglCreateWindowSurface fails with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

When trying to press the back button quickly during launching some Activities with `GLSurfaceView`, `eglCreateWindowSurface` fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

I got the following errors:

```
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): eglCreateWindowSurface
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Make sure the SurfaceView or associated SurfaceHolder has a valid Surface
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): at com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLImpl._eglCreateWindowSurface(Native Method)
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): at com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLImpl.eglCreateWindowSurface(EGLImpl.java:90)
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$DefaultWindowSurfaceFactory.createWindowSurface(GLSurfaceView.java:798)
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.createSurface(GLSurfaceView.java:1065)
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1433)
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
```

These activities didn't invoke GL operations before `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceCreated` or after `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceDestroyed`.

Has anyone else run into this, and what's the solution?

Thanks for any advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Switching between multiple Activities quickly torn window surface down.

I patched `GLSurfaceView.guardedRun()` to avoid race condition of `GLSurfaceView`

from:

```
                if (createEglSurface) {
                    if (LOG_SURFACE) {
                        Log.w("GLThread", "egl createSurface");
                    }
                    gl = (GL10) mEglHelper.createSurface(getHolder());
                    if (gl == null) {
                        // Couldn't create a surface. Quit quietly.
                        break;
                    }
                    sGLThreadManager.checkGLDriver(gl);
                    createEglSurface = false;
                }
```

to:

```
                if (createEglSurface) {
                    if (LOG_SURFACE) {
                        Log.w("GLThread", "egl createSurface");
                    }
                    gl = (GL10) mEglHelper.createSurface(getHolder());
                    if (gl == null) {
                        // If we escape, GLThread ends up. Don't escape.
                        continue;
                    }
                    sGLThreadManager.checkGLDriver(gl);
                    createEglSurface = false;
                }
```

It looks to me like this problem was [fixed in JellyBean](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/7d73df83f9a28950f404e957eb2e4ea1e8525c55).

Comment: Good catch, thanks! I ended up backporting the whole class from Jelly Bean, for lack of any simple way to patch the one line.

Comment: How could you patch that one line? I got same problem. Could you please give me some hints. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AmyWuGo - add this file(https://gist.github.com/dalinaum/3890965) to your project.

Comment: @Dalinaum Thank you very much. I tried your source, and the frequency of the bug became lower, but not disappear completely. I think there mush be some other bugs in my app. Thanks.

Comment: @AmyWuGo There are some bugs on SurfaceView until JB. Check newest SurfaceView. It will be of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by setting a callback for surfaceDestroyed and calling super.surfaceDestroyed.

```
glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(context) {
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.surfaceDestroyed(holder);
    }
};
```

Comment: My problem wass not same case. See also my answer. Thanks anyway, @codeNinja.