# GLThread crash on some phones

Tags: android, opengl-es

I see in google analytics that my app crashes on some phones (Galaxy Y and more) and I can't figure out why. I have a VU-meter which is made using Open GL. 
The app is: "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.audioRec&hl=en"

Below is some stack traces taken from Analytics:

```
IllegalArgumentException (@EGLImpl:_eglCreateWindowSurface:-2) {GLThread 44}
RuntimeException (@GLSurfaceView$EglHelper:throwEglException:1099) {GLThread 85}
```

Comment: Which android versions were they running?

Comment: android 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably fix this issue by including a newer version of GLSurfaceView.java from say JB or onwards into your project, more info:

That crash is most likely due to Galaxy Y (that run Gingerbread?) does not contain the fix described  [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/7d73df83f9a28950f404e957eb2e4ea1e8525c55) also user @Dalinaum made an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12891483/2246121) to a similar question.